# python3 path only running google-appengine modules

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, path

When running django projects with python3 or installing modules with pip, I am getting google-appengine errors, even if my project is not using google appengine.

When running pip3 freeze I get the following results:

```
andrew@andrew:~/dev/quickistock$ pip3 freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 10, in <module>
    from distutils.command.install import install, SCHEME_KEYS  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/distutils/distutils/command/install.py", line 258
    raise DistutilsOptionError, \
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Running the command with sudo yields no errors

Answer (score 0):

The file `usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/distutils/distutils/command/install.py`  has lines like [this](https://github.com/theosp/google_appengine/blob/9ce87a20684dc99cf5968e6f488c060e1530c159/lib/distutils/distutils/command/install.py#L325) and is compatible with python 2.1. **Note**. this is not the official google repository but it's accurate:

```
print "config vars:"
```

This means that `install.py` is a python 2 file and you are running pip from python 3. There probably is some incompatibility between them.